# TLS issue: failed to create a gRPC client for target

Tags: ssl, grpc, tls1.3

I am trying to implement TLS authentication.

On server side, I have configured gNMI server on mimic([documented here](https://doc.gambitcom.com/mimic/gnmi.htm)).
gNMI is build on top of gRPC.

On client side, I am making use of openconfig's gnmic [utility](https://github.com/openconfig/gnmic) to collect data.

I have root certificate copied on gnmic side and corresponding TLS certificate and key on gNMI server in mimic.

When I use insecure connection, things work fine.
But when I use tls-ca option with gnmic command:

```
gnmic -u admin -p admin --tls-ca /path/to/root-ca -a <ip>:<port> capabilities
```

I get error:

```
target ".......", capabilities request failed: failed to create a gRPC client for target ......: context deadline exceeded
Error: one or more requests failed
```

I am not able to find the root cause.
Any input is appreciated.

PS: With -d option, I see this:

```
transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```